# how to get the node author link

Tags: 7, users

In the node.tpl, how do i just get the `$author` profile page url?

with the `$submitted`, it prints out other things, all i need is just something like this:

```
<a href="$url">$author</a>
```

I've also used `$name`, but this only gives the name without a link.

I would also like to get the link to the current user's profile. Again, just need the username with their profile url only.

Comment: i just found out, the $name does out put the link, but it needs to active profile view for public/authentic users in the permissions first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = l("user/" . $node->uid);
```

Comment: this is a good one too!